# sort PHP foreach array alphabetical order

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Trying to figure out a way to display each folder sorted by the first words. the data array is random, so it is never in this order. You cannot use the numbers. For example I want it displayed as:

```
INBOX
INBOX.Drafts
INBOX.Test
INBOX.Test.Sub Test Folder
INBOX.Trash
```

This is the array:

```
Array
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [mailbox] => INBOX.Test.Sub Test Folder
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [mailbox] => INBOX.Junk
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [mailbox] => INBOX.Test
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [mailbox] => INBOX
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [mailbox] => INBOX.Drafts
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [mailbox] => INBOX.Trash
                )

        )
)
```

Comment: Have you tried using [`usort()`](https://secure.php.net/usort)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `array_column` to extract those values, and then sorting is easy:

```
$output = array_column($input["data"], "mailbox");
sort($output);
```